# H192 Pixel Barrier on MainPage

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sdk

This is an intermittent problem where the top 192 pixels of the application paint and work perfectly, but everything in the browser below that is white and does not respond to clicks.

This started about a month ago, but has not occurred on the development machine until today.  On the test server, it has been happening with different browsers at different times, but it fails much more often on Firefox, Chrome, and IE 8 than on IE 7.  Sometimes the entire client area of the browser is white, not just the part below 192 pixels; I’m assuming this is a related problem, but I’m not sure.

On the development machine today, it fails on IE (both the Visual Studio internal browser and IE 8) and FF, but works under Chrome.

Here are the details:

1. Silverlight 4, Entity Framework 4 with RIA Services, and VS 2010.
2. Using breakpoints in the debugger, I see that the ActualHeight of MainPage becomes 192 pixels.
3. If I manually set MinHeight or Height to 1000 pixels, then ActualHeight in the debugger will be 1000, but everything below 192 pixels is still white.
4. ActualHeight is 0 until immediately after the constructor for MainPage returns, when the debugger shows its ActualHeight is 192.
5. The constructor contains only a single statement -- InitializeComponent();
6. I set the background color of MainPage to green, and everything below 192 is still white.
7. There is a border around the contents of MainPage.  The border looks normal, except that the bottom it has been truncated, so everything is white below 192 pixels.
8. I have removed most of the content of MainPage and modified the code so that only Application_Startup (containing only this.RootVisual = new MainPage();) and the constructor for MainPage (containing only InitializeComponent();) are called.  I also verified in the debugger (using breakpoints and single stepping) that nothing else is executed.  The problem still occurs exactly as before.

Can anyone suggest a fix or further diagnostic?  Thanks in advance.

DEFAULT.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="iVG.Web.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>iVoterGuide.com</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost {
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            var appSource = "";
            if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
                appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
            }

            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
                return;
            }

            var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + appSource + "\n";

            errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
            errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
            errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

            if (errorType == "ParserError") {
                errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
                if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                    errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                    errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
                }
                errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
            }

            throw new Error(errMsg);
        }
        function CloseMainWindow(x) {
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('SilverlightControl').focus();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> <%--style="height:100%"--%>
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object id="SilverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/iVG.xap"/>
          <param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
               <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

MAINPAGE.XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource GridRoot}" Background="Green" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridMenu}" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Sticky:Tab x:Name="TabMenu" DisplayMemberPath="Text" Style="{StaticResource MainTabMenu}" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="TabMenu_SelectionChanged" Margin="0"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeSmall}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" x:Name="BlockSignedIn"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border x:Name="BorderContent" Style="{StaticResource BorderContent}">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,-6,-2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeSmall}" Foreground="Black" x:Name="BlockTimestamp"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderPageHeader}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BlockHeader" Style="{StaticResource BlockPageHeader}" Text=""/>
                    </Border>
                    <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrame}" MinHeight="300" Navigating="ContentFrame_Navigating"
                            Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                            <sdk:UriMapper>
                                <sdk:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                            </sdk:UriMapper>
                        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                    </navigation:Frame>
                    <Grid Height="5"/>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderPageFooter}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BlockVersion"/>
                    </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Grid  Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" x:Name="GridDebug">
            <TextBlock Text="DEBUG" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Margin="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, although I have no idea why.  In the line below on page Default.aspx, I changed
    height="100%"
to
    height="2000"

```
<object id="SilverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```

If "height" is omitted or if it is "auto," it still doesn't work.  It also fails (in a different way) if "height" is too large - e.g. 5000.